# How to build custom library with SolidJs

Tags: frontend, shared-libraries, vite, solid-js

I'm actually struggling on how to build a custom lib with solidJs framework

1. how to build the lib
2. how to use the lib in a Solidjs app

i'm using viteJs as a build tool

Thanks alot.

Comment: What kind of library? A set of custom primitives? components? do you want to ship CSS styles with the library? You can check out https://github.com/solidjs-community/solid-lib-starter for an easy start with a new library. Using vite is not what we usually recommend for building a library - you need to be able to emit "solid" entry with preserved JSX if you want to use your components in SSR, and I haven't seen it pulled off with vite.

Comment: Yes that's it, i plan to create a lib with custom primitives and components in order to share it. no i do not plan to use it in SSR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean JavaScript modules by library, then there is nothing extra ordinary about SolidJS signals and components. They are just regular JavaScript functions and variables. You can create and export them from your library and import them in an another app or module.

NPM libraries are JavaScript modules with a `package.json` file that sets entry points and dependency requirements.

You may be wondering if you need to add solid-js as a dependency, probably not because the front-end application does that, a library should not concern itself with the application's dependencies. However you can add `solid-js` as a dev dependency or peer dependency.

About the CSS dependencies. It totally depends on your setup and how you are going to style elements. If you are using vite and CSS modules, then you can define CSS modules in your library and use them in your components. When you import a component, the component will pull the CSS modules it uses and bundlers will do the rest. It is same for static files etc.